# Same IHostedService in multiple instances

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, kubernetes, ihostedservice

I need to create a process (in a Kubernetes cluster) that updated a register, in a table, every hour.
By the moment, in my kubernetes, I deploy only net core apis.

My first option was to make an IHostedService (as a SchedulerJob) over one of the apis related with de context of the process but then I have a dubt: If the api deploy in multiples instances, that's can be a problem related with the data concurrence? Someone knows how to avoid that? Maybe it's a bad idea?

Thanks in advances

Comment: Could you describe in more details what process would you like to create? Periodic and recurring tasks can be created using cronjobs: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/cron-jobs/#cronjob

Comment: @KFC_Thanks! this a possibleank option but, I thinks, that possibility obligues me to translate the context (that I have in my api) in a different project

Comment: What do you mean by translating context in your API?

Comment: Sorry abaout my english....when I say "context" I'm refere about Services, DataBase Access....if you make the IHostedService inside (or injected) in a Api it's easy to use the context of the api....However if tou create a new service, you  need to create a new context